# Which would be a correct workflow in a CI/CD environment when obfuscating, minification, SAST/DAST security tests, etc., before deploying?

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm working in creating a full CI/CD environment including all the needed steps from the compilation of the source code to the deployment in a container like Docker. It is a full stack application that includes frontend and backend layers. Angular for front, Java for back, according to the specifications I have.

I'm learning about how to implement the workflow of the tasks that must be performed to complete the process. I've been researching about all of the following concepts: For the Frontend, tasks like obfuscaton or minification. For both front and back, code coverage, SAST and DAST tests, and performance tests (load, resistance, volume, scalability, stress, etc.).

I've worked before in simple CI/CD pojects where I had my code in Java, upload the code to Git, having a pipeline in Jenkins to check if a new push was done in Git and test it, and if succeeded, deploy the application in a Docker container.

With all these new steps, after understanding what they are, I am trying to guess how to order them in this process of [Code - GIT - Jenkins - Docker]. What comes first, and what comes after, to have a picture in my mind of the order I must follow when designing the whole process.

I've seen that Jenkins can run SAST and DAST test (I've never done before) using some plugins, like the OWASP ones or SonarQube (after googling I don't know which one would be better). For Code Coverage I know that the unitary tests coded in my project will feed the Code Coverage functionality of the IDE (I'm using IntelliJ) to retrieve the results in the IDE, but I've heard about JACOCO as a plugin for Jenkins, and also I've read that SonarQube has something for the Code Coverage.

Which would be the correct order to have a reliable workflow in the CI/CD environment? In my mind I have the following:

All the workflow starting after Git, and before Docker, I would do it using Jenkins, as I've seen that there are plugins available for almost all the steps I want to follow.

- For Frontend: [Source Code -> Git -> Code Coverage testing -> SAST -> Dependency-Check -> Minification -> Obfuscation -> DAST -> Deployment]
- For Backend: [Source Code -> Git -> Code Coverage testing -> SAST -> Dependency-Check -> DAST -> Deployment]

Also I've read about performance tests in Jenkins, but couldn't find plugins for that (stress, scalability, load, volume, etc.), and I don't know which would be the best momnt to do them, if after DAST, after the code coverage step or after deploy the application

Tools that I've seen that could be valid for this (among others):

- Code Coverage: JUnit, SonarQube, JACOCO
- SAST: Warning Next Generation plugin, SonarQube, CodeQL
- Dependency Check: OWASP Dependency-Check
- DAST: SonarQube, OWASP ZAP

Is correct the order I've described above in order to have a correct CI/CD process? I wouldn't like to perform DAST tests before Code Coverage, or Obfuscation before Minification  or things like that to avoid problems in the process.

Thanks for any help you could give me.

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents:

First, things don't have to be sequential: in mostCI/CD pipelines, things are run in parallel: you can run code coverage in parallel with building/minifying the code, or with DAST/SAST testing. Parallel runs will be faster.

Second, you want to fail fast: if the build fails, the rest is useless. If coverage fails a threshold, you might want to push to prod anyway in some circumstances, so some steps are hard stops while some others are soft stops. Hard stops should come first (or in parallel) as much as possible to fail fast.

Comment: Thanks @MrE! This clarifies me many things. Let me ask, which steps could be considered as "hard stops"? I guess that the correct compilation of the code is one of them, but what more could be considered as a hard one? When creating the workflow, I can consider that from one specific step, let say the compilation with no errors (hard), I can run in parallel the soft ones but I you would have to specify which ones of them were soft, which ones of them you run in parallel? You think I'm missing some tasks, or the ones I've described could cover all the requirements for a professional software?